# display a chart js with data table

Tags: javascript, charts

```
for (var i = 0; i < valueInfo.length; i++) {
  if (++conteur === valueInfo.length) {            
    MydataPoints+='{  y: '+parseInt(valueInfo[i])+', indexLabel: "Feminin" }';
  }
  else {
    MydataPoints+='{  y: '+parseInt(valueInfo[i])+', indexLabel: "Feminin" },';
  }
}
```

result of MydataPoints is = ["{  y: 3, indexLabel: "Feminin" },{  y: 5, indexLabel: "Feminin" }"]

But for working chart in need like this array : [{ y: 3, indexLabel: "Feminin" },{  y: 5, indexLabel: "Masculin"}]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please review this article for best results when using this site:  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is to build JSON string manually, whereas ChartJS required JSON object.

```
 [{ y: 3, indexLabel: "Feminin" },{ y: 5, indexLabel: "Masculin"}]
```

This is valid JSON string and you are trying to build this manually into JS.
Instead, try fetching data from server itself into JSON format and it will give you proper JSON string,

for your manual operation into JSON you can loop through ajax response or take care for it into server logic.

Still, if you need to work on JS manually, instead of JSON binding try making HTML markup for ChartJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MydataPoints=[]
if(++conteur === valueInfo.length) {            
        MydataPoints.push({  y:parseInt(valueInfo[i]), "indexLabel": "Feminin" });
      }
      else{
        MydataPoints.push({  y:parseInt(valueInfo[i]), "indexLabel": "Feminin"});     };
```

Comment: the result of this code is [{"y":3,"indexLabel":"Feminin"},{"y":5,"indexLabel":"Feminin"}] but i need this result [{y:3,indexLabel:"Feminin"},{y:5,indexLabel:"Feminin"}] before y i need y and not "y"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var valueInfo = ["12","13"];
var MydataPoints = [];

for (var i = 0; i < valueInfo.length; i++) {          
  MydataPoints.push({
    y: parseInt(valueInfo[i]),
    indexLabel: "Feminin" 
  });
};

var div = document.getElementById('text');

div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(MydataPoints);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Merciiii but :/ 
the result of this code is [{"y":3,"indexLabel":"Feminin"},{"y":5,"indexLabel":"Feminin‌​"}] but i need this result [{y:3,indexLabel:"Feminin"},{y:5,indexLabel:"Feminin"}] before y i need y and not "y"

Comment: I think you are confusing a javascript object/array with it's JSON string. For ChartJS you need to give a JSON string if you are adding the data manually to your code, but you need to give a javascript Array if you are creating it dynamically. I think the problem is somewhere else in the code than what you posted to us.